# Laravel 8 - Listen to eloquent events made during a specific request

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Currently, I'm trying to wire a telemetry library (OpenTelemetry php lib) to the Laravel event model. The idea is to forward traces to a third party service. A single trace consistents of a request and all database calls that have been made during the request. I've created three middleware components:

- BeforeRequest: starts a trace
- OnRequest: call event listener which listened to DB queries (see snippet below) and end trace so that it is send to a third party service

My OnRequest middleware component looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Helpers\Otel\TraceProviderFactory;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class OnRequest
{
     public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
     {
         $provider = TraceProviderFactory::getTraceProvider($request->get('context_uuid'));
         DB::listen(function (QueryExecuted $query) use ($provider){
              $provider->startDbSpan($query);
         });
         $provider->endSpans();

         return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In this case, the DB listen call is skipped over because it is async. How can I make sure that each database query is registered? The execution order is important. Everything needs to be in the right order otherwise the traces aren't logged properly.

Comment: DB::listen is not async because php does not provide async by default it's just a callback that runs when a DB or model has been queried, are you sure that you have query or model fired? did you try to use Log::debug() and look in laravel.log

Comment: you are saying this `endSpans` method is the one that is supposed to send off the trace?

Comment: @Jerson Yes, I've checked. It gets skipped over. After the endSpans() call the dbSpan() is called

Comment: @lagbox Correct. Of course, I could order them but how am I sure that all the DB requests are there?

Comment: why are you saying it gets skipped over?  things run linearly, there are no queries between you listening for them and you ending this  .... i think you are looking for a "terminable" middleware to add that method call (after the response has been sent off) or at the least an "after middleware" ... this way the request is at least going through the middleware stack to the 'action' and the response is making its way out to this middleware

Comment: Okay good to know. I assuming that because that is the order that I'm seeing when I add dump statements to determine the execution flow.

Comment: @markvdlaan93 are you sure that there are queries to listen? if yes then the DB::listen will call that callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the finalizing of this in a terminable middleware (after the response has been sent to the client) to allow you to log all the queries made from the time you start listening until the Response is sent. This also won't hold up returning the response to the client.

```
...

class OnRequest
{
     protected $provider;

     public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
     {
         $this->provider = TraceProviderFactory::getTraceProvider($request->input('context_uuid'));

         DB::listen(function (QueryExecuted $query) {
              $this->provider->startDbSpan($query);
         });

         return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
         $this->provider->endSpans();
    }
}
```

You should make this middleware a singleton so that way it doesn't use a new instance for the terminable part. (We want that same `$provider` instance assigned). Register the singleton in a Service Provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(OnRequest::class);
}
```

You only need one middleware to do everything.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Middleware - Terminable Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#terminable-middleware)